# Scaling filesystem on centos whm and nginx webservers

Tags: linux, image, object, filesystems, scaling

We have built a marketplace for our clients, we have hundreds thousands of companies in our database and they will add their products with many files (images,videos etc.). And also individual users are able to send photos.

We are using centos +whm (nginx+cassandra+mysql+redis+nodejs+php+java) for different parts of project according to their different content.

For main software we are using mysql and cassandra as database servers, there are restful java webservices between php7 code and database servers (which are already scaled).nodejs+redis+cassandra (for chat)

We have no problems for scaling information, but now we have to decide how to scale objects. The company which we work supplies 10TB bandwidth for each server that we get. If we consider to work with amazon or other cloud services, only for 10TB bandwidth they will charge a lot, on the other hand in this case we will have another server which will be used for other issues as well. So it seems better to have servers instead of cloud storage.

Now my question is how should we go ahead for statics files ? What is the best solution for this.

Creating nodes with subdomains like static1.domain.com, static2.domain.com for each new server. and add image location to database to show location of image. in this case for upload we always need to change target mounted disk after each server is full. We will also use CDN to decrease loads on servers.

What is the best architecture for our situation ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a one option in Amazon Web Services (s3). that is not a file system but you can store your static files in that s3 bucket. It will auto increase/decrease storage size based on data size and also data 99.99999999999% availability.

FYR,
[AWS-s3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)